# Keras: How to store history after each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to change my input after every epoch and at the end I want to plot learning curve.

To change the input I have function which I can use as below

```
for _ in range(num_epochs):
    x, y = generate_data()
    history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

But I am not able to capture the complete history for my model. How can I access it and plot learning curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the `history`.

```
history_dict = dict()

for i in range(num_epochs):
    x, y = generate_data()
    history_dict['epoch_%i' % i] = model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

It will give something like that:

```
Out[4]: 
{'epoch_0': <your history 1>,
 'epoch_1': <your history 2>,
 'epoch_2': <your history 3>,
```

Comment: Thank you. But with this,  what I get is a dictionary containing history item, which I can not really access to plot learning curve.

Comment: you can access it like `history_dict['epoch_0'].history['loss']`. See the [docs](https://keras.io/visualization/).

Comment: Thank you this way I can access now. But I have one more issue. Can I just plot the curve like this? or Am I doing something wrong? Because when I try to run it gives me keyerror.                                                                                                 '''for i in range(num_epoch):
      plt.plot(history_dict[i].history['loss'])
      plt.show()'''

Comment: You can't index a dictionary with an integer (number). You have to index it with the name. E.g., `history_dict['epoch_0']` works but `history_dict[0]` won't work

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I really want to achieve is to plot a curve (loss) for all epochs (as it is shown in the document that you have mentioned earlier). But with this dictionary I am not able to access all values at a time and plot a curve rather I can access one value at a time. If you can clear this doubt, it would be of great help.

Comment: It's best to ask only one question on S/O. I think the issue of storing all the epochs is solved. I'm guessing you need to plot all lines on a single plot? That is more a question about iterating through a dictionary or something about matplotlib. If you break down your problem there are plenty of existing questions on this site that can help. I'm still not sure what you mean by "accessing all values at the same time"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I could solve one of the issue. I will look into other.